# Woocommerce - Hook when a coupon is created

Tags: woocommerce, hook, hook-woocommerce

For woocommerce: is there a hook fired when a woocommerce coupon is created?

I need to add this hook in myTheme/functions.php to fire an action just at a coupon creation.

**UPDATE**:

I included this code in my functions.php but it doesn't seem to work. It should print "it works" at coupon creation but it doesn't. No error, nothing at all.

```
function after_new_coupon_created( $coupon_id, $coupon ){
    echo "it works";
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_coupon', 'after_new_coupon_created', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: [yes](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/e0516c475dbc6267f16a17849234f101e83680c2/plugins/woocommerce/includes/data-stores/class-wc-coupon-data-store-cpt.php#L99)

Comment: @AlonEitan I don't get how to use this code. I need to add this hook in myTheme/functions.php to fire an action.

Answer (score 1):

As Alon Eitan said in the comment you can use like below.

```
function after_new_coupon_created( $coupon_id, $coupon ){
    // your code here.
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_coupon', 'after_new_coupon_created', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: I guess I need to add the code that Alon posted to makes the action to work properly. Should I create custom plugin to embed the Alon's code?

Comment: No, you can add these code in your active theme functions.php

Comment: There is something wrong in these code. I just copy / pasted it into my functions.php file and the site shows a critical error message.

Comment: Did you check the error logs?

Comment: Yes, here:"Fatal error: Cannot declare class WC_Coupon_Data_Store_CPT, because the name is already in use in /usr/home/t16/www/wp-content/themes/flatsome-child/functions.php on line 708". Line 708 is this:

Comment: class WC_Coupon_Data_Store_CPT extends WC_Data_Store_WP implements WC_Coupon_Data_Store_Interface, WC_Object_Data_Store_Interface {

Comment: Look like you declaring the same class name again. please rename your class name.

Comment: Do you mean to rename this "WC_Coupon_Data_Store_CPT"?  --  I just tried with "WC_Coupon_Data_Store_CPT2" but the issue persists.

Comment: Please full code in your question with errors.

Comment: done, I added all in my question

Comment: I think you misunderstood Alon comment and my answer. You don't have to copy the entire code from the given link you just have to add code from my answer.

Comment: That's was the first that I tried, but it didn't work at all.

Comment: But what didn't work? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I just put the code in functions.php and try to echo a text which should be printed at a coupon creation. Just like this:

Comment: function after_new_coupon_created( $coupon_id, $coupon ){
    echo "It works";
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_coupon', 'after_new_coupon_created', 10, 2 );

Answer (score 0):

The
**woocommerce_coupon_options_save**
hook worked great for this. It can be used in conjunction with **woocommerce_coupon_options** to capture and save custom admin coupon options.

Example (adds coupon to all digital downloads):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_coupon_options', 'addCouponCheckbox', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_coupon_options_save', 'couponOptionsSaved', 10, 2 );

function addCouponCheckbox() {
    woocommerce_wp_checkbox( array(
        'id'                => 'is_digital_reading',
        'label'             => __( 'Is Reading download', 'woocommerce' ),
        'placeholder'       => '',
        'description'       => __( 'This coupon is designed for use with digital Readings.', 'woocommerce' ),
    ) );
}

function couponOptionsSaved( $post_id, $coupon ) {
    $idr = 'is_digital_reading';

    if ( isset( $_POST[$idr] ) ) {
        $products = wc_get_products( ['limit' => -1, 'status' => 'publish'] );
        $productIds = $coupon->get_product_ids();

        foreach($products as $id => $product) {
            $variations = $product->get_children();
    
            foreach($variations as $variationId) {
                $virtualProduct = wc_get_product($variationId);
    
                if (
                    $virtualProduct->is_virtual() &&
                    $virtualProduct->is_downloadable() &&
                    !in_array($variationId, $productIds)
                ) {
                    array_push($productIds, $variationId);
                }
            }
        }

        $coupon->set_discount_type("fixed_product");
        $coupon->set_amount(3);
        $coupon->set_limit_usage_to_x_items(1);
        $coupon->set_individual_use(true);
        $coupon->set_product_ids($productIds);
        $coupon->update_meta_data( $idr, sanitize_text_field( $_POST[$idr] ) );
    } else {
        $coupon->set_product_ids([]);
        $coupon->update_meta_data( $idr, false );
    }

    $coupon->save();
}
```